# How to add styling to ManytoMany field in forms(Django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzHXl.png)I am trying to add styling in my Django forms. I know how to add styling in single input fields but in manytomany fields, it display kind of weird which I don't like. I have tried to add classes in widgets attributes but it does not work.

This is my code.

```
#model.py

class Professor(models.Model):
professor_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
professor_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
professor_course = models.ManyToManyField(Course)
working_hours = models.IntegerField(null=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.professor_name

[#form.py

class CourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = \['course_id', 'course_name', 'course_type', 'per_week_classes'\]

    course_name = forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'course_name', 'class': 'form-control'})
    course_type = forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'course_type', 'class': 'form-control'})
    per_week_classes = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'id': 'per_week_classes', 'class': 'form-control'})

class ProfessorForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Professor
        fields = \['professor_name', 'professor_course', 'working_hours'\]][1]
```

This is how it looks now. I want to add search facility and styling to it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way using a python module,

```
pip install django-crispy-forms bootstrap4
```

add 'crispy_forms' in installed app settings

add `CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'` in settings.

in your html page add this on top `{% load crispy_forms_tags %}`

after csrf token tag add your forms like this  `{{ form|crispy }}`